# Move to next record based on specific value in textbox

Tags: vb.net

I am in need of some help. I want to be able to go through my records using the next and previous buttons on my form using a dynamic
values.

The code I currently have does moves to next record but from the starting value, however I want to be able to start from a specific value for example, if I type 100 
into textbox and click next it should display records for 101, 102 and so forth with each click.

How do I accomplish this. Many thanks

This is the current code i have at the moment.

```
Dim intcurrentindex As Integer = 0
If intcurrentindex < ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 Then
    intcurrentindex = intcurrentindex - 1

    TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intcurrentindex).Item("NAME").ToString
    TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intcurrentindex).Item("CODE").ToString
    TextBox3.Text = ds2.Tables(0).Rows(intcurrentindex).Item("STOCKNAME").ToString
    TextBox4.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intcurrentindex).Item("WEIGHT").ToString
    TextBox5.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intcurrentindex).Item("LOCATION").ToString

End If
```

Comment: Where do you take the input from your `TextBox`?  Have you tried adding a `TextBox` and using `Int32.TryParse` to get its value?

Comment: intcurrentindex is zero, then you subtract 1 from it, making intcurrentindex equal to -1.  Not sure how that's working.

Comment: @David - I'm not sure how to approach it. Can you explain. I take the input from textbox2

Comment: @user3562155: Well, where specifically are you stuck?  You claim that you take input from "textbox2", but where do you do that?  Are you just asking how to read the value of a `TextBox`?  That would be in its `.Text` property.  (Conveniently the same place you *write* a value to a `TextBox`.)  It's not clear where specifically you're stuck.

Comment: @David - I can input a value say 112 and retrieve the record but what I want it to do when I click the next button is to show the next consecutive records 113, 114 et. which is not currently doing. Instead when I click the next button, it will start from the first record say 100.

Comment: Use the [BindingNavigator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/bindingnavigator-control-overview-windows-forms)

Comment: @larstech - is there another way other than binding?

Comment: Binding is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
Public Class Form1

Private intcurrentindex As Integer = 0
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TxtCurrentIndex.Text = 0
End Sub

Private Sub BtnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnNext.Click

    If TxtCurrentIndex.Text = "" Then
        intcurrentindex = 0
    Else
        'set intcurrentindex to textbox value
        intcurrentindex = TxtCurrentIndex.text
    End If

    If intcurrentindex < ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 Then
        TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intcurrentindex).Item("NAME").ToString
        TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intcurrentindex).Item("CODE").ToString
        TextBox3.Text = ds2.Tables(0).Rows(intcurrentindex).Item("STOCKNAME").ToString
        TextBox4.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intcurrentindex).Item("WEIGHT").ToString
        TextBox5.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intcurrentindex).Item("LOCATION").ToString
        intcurrentindex = intcurrentindex + 1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BtnPrevius_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPrevius.Click

    If TxtCurrentIndex.Text = "" Then
        intcurrentindex = 0
    Else
        'set intcurrentindex to textbox value
        intcurrentindex = TxtCurrentIndex.text
    End If


    If intcurrentindex > 0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intcurrentindex).Item("NAME").ToString
        TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intcurrentindex).Item("CODE").ToString
        TextBox3.Text = ds2.Tables(0).Rows(intcurrentindex).Item("STOCKNAME").ToString
        TextBox4.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intcurrentindex).Item("WEIGHT").ToString
        TextBox5.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intcurrentindex).Item("LOCATION").ToString
        intcurrentindex = intcurrentindex - 1
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

you need a variable to store current index

Comment: fixed code, TxtCurrentIndex its the name of textbox where you enter record number

Comment: the code kind of works, but the numbers are not in sequence such as 100,101,102,103 and it crashes on certain records. It gives a "Conversion from string "00450ABC1" to type 'Integer' is not valid" error.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help on this. I used binding source in the end to get it to work.